# How to fill multiple pageobject textfield in real-time

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, page-object-gem

I am dealing with a problem and not able to find a smart solution. In brief: imagine we have many text field elements defined in page-object as:

```
 text_field(:txt_field_1, id: 'field1')
 text_field(:txt_field_2, id: 'field2')
 ....
```

I can easily fill one field with:

```
def fill_field1(content)
 self.txt_field_1 = content
end
```

...calling the method:

```
fill_field1('John Doe')
```

---

What i'm looking for is to use **a unique method to fill several fields**, using the page-object element name as method parameter, for example:

```
def fill_fields(field, content)
 self.field = content
end
```

...and calling the method this way:

```
fill_fields('txt_field_1', 'John Doe')
```

The above example fails with an "undefined method" error. I tried to use the `send()` method like `self.send('field') = 'John Doe'` unsuccessfully. I'm pretty sure there is a way to accomplish that... can you please shed some light on the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example, you could use the page-object gem's built in [`populate_page_with`](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/PagePopulator#populate_page_with-instance_method) method. Assuming the text fields are defined in the page object already, then you can do:

```
example_page.populate_page_with :txt_field_1 => 'John Doe'
```

Or do multiple fields like:

```
example_page.populate_page_with :txt_field_1 => 'John Doe', :txt_field_2 => 'Jane Doe'
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, you're right, but what i'm looking for is a way in which ":txt_field_1" is filled dynamically during execution, using a method with a parameter that we can even get form the step definition. I think that as Sawa pointed out, using a method with send("#{field}=", content) is a very smart way to accomplish what needed, and it works.

Comment: If you look into the code, that is exactly what the `populate_page_with` does. There is nothing stopping you from doing `example_page.populate_page_with field => content`.